# Passing value to controller from Ajax,controller receiving null value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How to pass value from AJAX to Controller.

I have designed a dropdown list and on selection AJAX will pass the selected item's ID to the controller. The controller will in return pass the same ID received,to the AJAX and it will be shown in an alert in the webpage.

But every time I debug my Controller function I get a null value in the received string.

AJAX Code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#underId").change(function () {
            var id = $('#underId :selected').val();
            alert(id);
            //if (id != null)
            { 
            //$("#acc_type").empty();
            //var json={GId : id};
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("FirstAjax","Group")',
                contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(id),

                success: function(data){

                    if (data.Success) { // this sets the value from the response
                        $('#underId').val(result.data);;

                    } else {
                        alert("Failed");
                    }


                }

            });
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller code :-

```
    public JsonResult FirstAjax(string id)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = true, Result = id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Change `data: JSON.stringify(id),` to `data: { id: id }`, remove `contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",` (and you can just use `var id = $(this).val();`). And to see the data the method returned, `alert(data.Result);`

Comment: In the AJAX callback you should access the returned ID with `data.Result`, not `result.data`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you,it worked.AJAX passed the value to the controller.But it didnt returned any value.

Comment: @ZoliSzabo I tried your method but didn't get any data from the controller

Comment: What do you mean it did not return any data? - it returns an object with 2 properties `Success ` and `Result` - and `console.log(data.Success);` will output `true`

Comment: Also, your controller method should set the content type to `application/json` (essentially what you have removed from the JS code, needs to be added to your controller).

Comment: @ZoliSzabo, There is no such thing as setting the content type in a controller. OP's controller code as shown is correct.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to show a value that will be returned from the controller.Take for example AJAX will send ID to the controller and controller will return (ID+1),that will be shown as an ALERT in the webpage.What changes needs to be done in the Controller and AJAX code?

Comment: Is `id` a number? If it is then the parameter should be `int id` (not `string`). And you could just use `return Json(id++, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and in the script `success: function(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I followed your alert(data.Result); and received data from Controller.Thank's a lot.You just changed the course of my project into the right direction.. :)

Comment: @SubhodeepBhattacharjee Ultimately, you've done your home work.

Comment: To be sure that the server returns properly formatted data, you could add the `error` callback to your AJAX request, something like: `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);}`. If something is wrong, this callback will be executed.

Comment: Yes Id is a number,but your first comment did the trick.Its working fine now.